# Using AOS with Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs3, aos.js

Anyone already used AOS or vue-aos package with Vue3?

I'm getting bunch of errors due probably to ssr (Vue is not defined, document is not defined) despite disabling in on config.

nuxt.config.ts

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/aos', mode: 'client', ssr: false }
  ],
}}
```

plugins/aos.ts

```js
import VueAOS from "vue-aos"

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VueAOS)
})
```

I tried this way, I tried the way with cdn files (but it leads to AOS is not defined when using .init() and both doesn't work. Every tutorial about AOS is related to Nuxt2.

I also tried to put `vue-aos` package on build.transpile on nuxt config without success.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

I also suffered with this problem of AOS not working in Nuxt3.

For me the sollution was to set the plugin in NuxtConfig to mode client like below:

```
plugins: [{ src: "@/plugins/aos", ssr: false, mode: "client" }],
```

After that I get a problem document is not defined. This was because when the window is not defined, the document can't be found.

I fixed this with the code below in the aos.ts file in the plugins folder:

```
import AOS from "aos"

import "aos/dist/aos.css"

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    nuxtApp.AOS = AOS.init() // eslint-disable-line new-cap
  }
})
```

I hope this will work for you also!

Comment: Thanks it helped, it's kinda vague in the docs how to handle window object

Answer (score 3):

From the [Nuxt docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins):

> All plugins in your `plugins/` directory are auto-registered, so you should not add them to your nuxt.config separately.

So with `"nuxt": "^3.1.1"` I just put

```
import AOS from 'aos'

import 'aos/dist/aos.css'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        nuxtApp.AOS = AOS.init()
    }
})
```

in a `plugins/aos.client.ts` file.

From the same docs: "You can use .server or .client suffix in the file name to load a plugin only on the server or client side."

Answer (score 1):

nuxt.config.ts

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt3'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vue: {
    compilerOptions: {
      isCustomElement: tag => ['aos-vue'].includes(tag)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found it pretty easy to get started, follow this steps and you're good to go

1- Install the package using `yarn add -D aos` or `npm i --save aos`

2- create `aos.ts` file in plugins folder and copy this into it

3- Restart the dev server

```
import AOS from 'aos';
import 'aos/dist/aos.css';
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {  
 if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {    
   nuxtApp.AOS = AOS.init();  
 }
});
```

That's it. Try to add `data-aos="zoom-in"` or any effect to a div and it'll work

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with AOS CSS, my app cannot find css file in aos. Then, I linked AOS with CDN. And, it helped:)